# How to justify that this set if infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I have a doubt about how to justify why this set is infinite.

The question (about the set I'm talking about) is this:

" 
a and b are real numbers.

a < b

So a < (a+b)/2 < b

which means the set a < x < b (x being a real number too) is not empty.

But it's also infinite. Explain why."

So I took the definition of an infinite set, which is "having an injective function with domain N and codomain ]a,b["

But now I'm thinking... If x is a real number, why can't our injective function have domain R... Is it impossible to happen? Or is it best to choose N as the domain because it's more guaranteed?

It's just a detail, but it made me think about it...

Thanks!

Comment: If you can find an injective function whose domain is $\mathbb R$ (and it's possible to do so), then the set will be infinite.But this isn't a direct consequence of the definition so why not just use the definition? Anyway, if you can find an injective function whose domain is $\mathbb R$, just restrict it to $\mathbb N$ to have a suitable candidate to use in the definition of infinite set.

Comment: If you use domain $\mathbb{N}$ you can prove it is at least *countably* infinite (which is arguably the "least" type of infinite), but if you happen to use domain $\mathbb{R}$ you can prove it is *uncountably* infinite (which is also infinite, but a "larger" type of infinite than simply being countably so).  As GitGud says, if the goal is simply showing that the set is infinite, it is going to be easier to show it *at least countably* so.

Answer (score 1):

If your injective function has domain $\Bbb R$ you have proved even more.  You have proved that the codomain is uncountably infinite (which it is here), but you were not asked for that.  You have found one number in $(a,b)$, which can be the image of $1$.  Now can you use the number you found to find another?  That one can be the image of $2$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$\{a < x < b\}$ is not empty so there is a number $x_0$ in the set so $a< x_0 < b$.  But is $\{a < x < x_0\}$ Empty?  Nope for the same reason you gave.  So there is a number $x_1$ such that $a < x_1 < x_0 < b$.  Repeat inductively to get an infinite number of these $x_i$ all of which are in $\{a < x < b\}$

or… you have found the midpoint of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{a+b}2$.  What is the midpoint of $a$ and $\frac{a+b}2$?  What is the midpoint between $a$ and that midpoint?  And between $a$ and the midpoint of *that*?